# Receive pipeline to unescape XML

Tags: xml, biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-2013

We use an MSMQ type receive location, but have noticed when it receives messages they contain escaped XML.
I'm thinking I need a receive pipeline to unescape it, can anyone tell me what component(s) should be used?  I can't see anything obvious in the toolbox.

thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you think this?  There's no specific reason MSMQ or the stack around it wold escape any string content, so something feels off about this.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing.  The port picking up from the MSMQ port fails as it tries to pick the message up, it can't route it as it can't identify what it is.  When I look at the message it's escaped.  When I pass the same message in through a file pick-up port it's not escaped.

Comment: I would first go to the app that pushes the message to see if they are the ones escaping it.

Comment: You're right - the app pushing out to MSMQ escapes the XML

Comment: Ah ha!  So, can they not do that?

Comment: 3rd part app, too much hassle/cost/time to get them to change it Im afraid. Not to worry, we've mapped the message to the corrcet schema which removes the string envelope and unescapes, so it's all good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very nice tool out there which helps you a lot in being able to create a pipeline component from scratch. It will create the 'bodywork' for a pipeline component, so you can start development right away.

The tool is called: [BizTalk Server Pipeline Component Wizard](https://btsplcw.codeplex.com/)

Once this is in place, create a custom receive pipeline component.

Depending on what [stage of the receive pipeline component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee268059(v=bts.10).aspx) you would want the pipeline component to execute, you will need to get your hands dirty and copy and 'change' the message.

Here is a nice blog article which gives a nice overview, step-by-step, on how to do the above (with exception of the editing):

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2012/01/24/creating-a-custom-biztalk-2010-pipeline-componentndashpart-i.aspx

And here is a nice link which gives a sample on how you would potentially change a message in a pipeline component:

https://dipeshavlani.net/2011/04/15/modifying-xml-document-in-a-custom-pipeline-component/

Hope this helps!